# Unable to align the items on same line on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I am having a design issue. I want to create a div that will expand on hover and will show some rating options. Till now I was able to design the basic layout but I am unable to make it work properly. As you can refer to this gif image and codes, The design is getting broken. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

One more point I forgot to mention I need to make this design responsive for small screen devices as you can see in my CSS I have used some values in px, which is not a good approach. I also need some suggestions on those points also.

Note - I am going to use this layout in the reactJs project I have shared the design part only and on the gif image you can see a slider, Which I have created using a reactJs package, which is working fine. But I am having a problem with this star rating design.

[image: Gif image showing the design break]

```css
/* CSS Variable Declaration */
:root {
    --main-theme-blue-color: #2D62A6;
    --main-theme-darkblue-color :#184279;
    --main-theme-white-color: #FFFFFF;
    --main-theme-gray-color: #9E9E9E;
    --theme-text-color: #3A3A3A;
    --font-weight-600: 600;
    --font-weight-500: 500;
    --font-weight-400: 400;
    --font-weight-300: 300;
    --hero-box-heading: 2rem;
    --main-heading: 1.5rem;
    --vertical-card-height: 300px;
    --horizontal-card-height: 180px;
    --iceberg-blue: #A9E3F0;
    --orange-colour: #F2911C;
    --font-size-90per: 90%;
    --font-size-80per: 80%;
    --strike-price: #FF005E;
}

/* CSS filter section */
.hotel-filter-heading {
    font-size: var(--main-heading);
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-600);
    line-height: 30px;
}

.hotel-filter-description {
    display: block;
    top: 4.6rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--theme-text-color);
}

.price-filter,
.pay-later-filter,
.type-of-property {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: var(--main-theme-blue-color);
    font-size: var(--font-size-90per);
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-500);
    padding: 0.1rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border: 2px solid var(--main-theme-blue-color);
}

.price-filter:hover,
.pay-later-filter:hover,
.type-of-property:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.grow-price-slider {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    width: 71px;
    transition: width 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.grow-price-slider .price-slider-bar {
    display: none;
    width: 0px;
    transition: width 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.grow-price-slider:hover {
    width: 188px;
}

.grow-price-slider:hover .price-slider-bar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}

.price-slider-bar .rc-slider-track {
    background-color: var(--main-theme-blue-color);
}

.price-slider-bar .rc-slider-handle {
    border-color: var(--main-theme-blue-color);
}

.grow-type-property {
    width: 153px;
    transition: width 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.grow-type-property .type-property-slider {
    display: none;
    width: 0px;
    transition: width 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.grow-type-property:hover {
    width: 400px;
}

.grow-type-property:hover .type-property-slider {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 247px;
}

.star-ratings {
    margin: 0rem 0.5rem;
}

.star-ratings i {
    margin: 0rem 0.1rem;
}

.three-star-color {
    color: #73BF9B;
}

.four-star-color {
    color: #0FA0BF;
}

.five-star-color {
    color: #F2C71C;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="hotel-filter-heading">Hotels in Kolkata</div>
      <div class="hotel-filter-description">Showing Results for 15 September to 18 September</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mt-4 mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span class="pay-later-filter mr-2">Pay Later</span>
      <span class="type-of-property grow-type-property">Type of Property
        <span class="type-property-slider">
          <span class="star-ratings">
            <i class="fa fa-star three-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star three-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star three-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>

          <span class="star-ratings">
            <i class="fa fa-star four-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star four-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star four-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star four-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>

          <span class="star-ratings">
            <i class="fa fa-star five-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star five-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star five-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star five-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star five-star-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what I can gather from the design is your div does not have the space for rating when hovered. But after the width animation is finished, it makes space for the rating stars. Try making them visible after the width animation is done.
For responsiveness, you can align them vertically on mobile instead of horizontally which should make space for the mobile.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @vishugosain. I have also tried that in that case, it's working fine but I am unable to achieve the transition animation. Can you share the code snippet? for better understanding.